# Interpreting the coefficients when predictors are standarised

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, standardization

Let's say I have a model of the form:

```
mdl <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=dat)
```

I am interested in knowing the relationship between `x3` and `y` when `x1` and `x2` remain unchanged. To do this, I do the following:

```
dat$x1 <- mean(dat$x1)
dat$x2 <- mean(dat$x2)
dat$x3 <- dat$x3

pred <- predict(mdl, data=dat)
mean(pred)
```

If I interpret `mean(pred)` correctly, it represents average change in `y` with a unit change in `x3` while keeping `x2` and `x1` constant. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Now imagine a second model where`x1`, `x2` and `x3` are standardised.

```
dat$z.x1 <- scale(dat$x1,scale = T,center = T)
dat$z.x2 <- scale(dat$x2,scale = T,center = T)
dat$z.x3 <- scale(dat$x3,scale = T,center = T)

mdl1 <- lm(y ~ z.x1 + z.x2 + z.x3, data=dat)

# keeping x1 and x2 at their mean values (which is zero since the variables 
are standardised)  

dat$z.x1 <- 0
dat$z.x2 <- 0
dat$z.x3 <- dat$z.x3

pred.z <- predict(mdl1, data=dat)

mean(pred.z)
```

This is where my question is. Does `mean(pred.z)` has the same interpretation as `mean(pred)` in the previous model? Can `mean(pred.z)` be interpreted as mean change in `y` with a unit change in `x3` while keeping `x2` and `x1` constant. OR

Does `mean(pred.z)` represent mean change in `y` when `x3` changes by one standard deviation since I had standardised `x3` in this model?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing more work than necessary to know "the relationship between `x3` and `y` when `x1` and `x2` remain unchanged," and at first glance you seem to be making an error in your approach (if I understand it properly).

The regression coefficient for `x3` in your first model is precisely the change in `y` per unit change in `x3` with the other predictors held constant. In your second model, with `x3` standardized before the regression, the regression coefficient for `z.x3` is the change in `y` per one-standard-deviation change in `x3`, again with the other predictors held constant.

Using `predict()` and `mean()`:

```
pred <- predict(mdl, data=dat)
mean(pred)
```

after setting all the other predictors to their mean values doesn't seem, at first glance, to give you what you are looking for. It gives you the mean `y` prediction for a data set that kept the original `x3` values but kept all of the other predictors at their individual means. The distribution of predicted `y` values would thus be very dependent on the distribution `x3` values and wouldn't necessarily bear any relation to "the relationship between `x3` and `y` when `x1` and `x2` remain unchanged." It's easy to come up with a scenario in which the mean of predicted `y` values would be 0 even with a strong linear relation between `y` and `x3`. If I'm missing something in your approach, please clarify.

In your second model, the pre-scaling of `x3` will lead to a corresponding change in the regression coefficient for `z.x3` so it seems that the final predicted `y` values with

```
pred.z <- predict(mdl1, data=dat)
mean(pred.z)
```

should be the same numerically as in the first model, although I haven't checked that directly.

Again, the regression coefficients themselves provide directly your answer.

Comment: Great. Thank you. What the background of the question is that I am trying to do produce a response function of  `y` and `x3`. So I plotted the predicted value of `y` against `x3` when `x1` and `x2` are held constant.

Comment: @user53020 plotting predicted `y` values against `x3` values should be OK; the issue is with taking the mean of the predicted `y` values. Again, you shouldn't have to work so hard to make a plot; to plot a response function in R you could just use the `abline()` function with the slope equal to the coefficient for `x3` and the intercept chosen appropriately based on `x1` and `x2` values. No need to go back to the original data once the regression is done. You could even plot a family of response functions based on sets of {`x1`,`x2`} values.